# Find all the number in a string which are separated by commas in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a a column of string. The data does not follow any particular format.
I need to find all numbers which are separated by commas.

For example,

```
string = "There are 5 people in the class and their heights 3,9,6,7,4".
```

I want to just extract the number 3,9,6,7,4 without the number 5.
I ultimately want to concatenate the word before the first number to each number. i.e heights3,heights9,heights6,heights7,heights4.

```
ExampleString = "There are 5 people in the class and their heights are 3,9,6,7,4"
temp = re.findall(r'\s\d+\b',ExampleString)
```

Here I get number 5 as well.

Comment: `4` is not followed by a number though.

Comment: The word before the numbers is `are`; should the string be `are3,are9,are6,are7,are4`, or do you want the second word before the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the commnents the `4` isn't followed by any number (so leaving it out):

```
>>> t = "There are 5 people in the class and their heights are 3,9,6,7,4"
>>> 'heights'+'heights'.join(re.findall(r'\d+,', t)).rstrip(',')
'heights3,heights9,heights6,heights7'
```

And if you want to include it you can:

```
>>> 'heights'+'heights'.join(re.findall(r'\d+,|(?<=,)\d+', t))
'heights3,heights9,heights6,heights7,heights4'
```

Comment: `t= "There are 5 people in the class and their heights are 3,what about this!!,9,6,7,4"` this will return the same result so he need to return number that are followed by comma not a number

Comment: Well, that's true, but my answer was based on the supplied text.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is your friend. You can solve your problem with just one line of code:

```
[int(n) for n in sum([l.split(',') for l in re.findall(r'[\d,]+[,\d]', test_string)], []) if n.isdigit()]
```

Ok, let's explain step by step:

The following code produced the list of string numbers delimited by comma:

```
test_string = "There are 5 people in the class and their heights are 3,9,6,7,4 and this 55,66, 77"
list_of_comma = [l for l in re.findall(r'[\d,]+[,\d]', test_string)]
# output: ['3,9,6,7,4', '55,66,', '77']
```

Divides `list_of_comma` and produces a list_of_lists of characters:

```
list_of_list = [l.split(',') for l in list_of_comma]
# output: [['3', '9', '6', '7', '4'], ['55', '66', ''], ['77']]
```

I use a trick to unpack the list of the list:

```
lst = sum(list_of_list, [])
# output: ['3', '9', '6', '7', '4', '55', '66', '', '77']
```

Convert each element to an integer and exclude non integers:

```
int_list = [int(n) for n in lst if n.isdigit()]
# output: [3, 9, 6, 7, 4, 55, 66, 77]
```

**EDIT**: if you want to format the numeric list in the required format:

```
keyword= ',heights'
formatted_res = keyword[1:] + keyword.join(map(str,res))
# output: 'heights3,heights9,heights6,heights7,heights4,heights55,heights66,heights77'
```

Comment: Better solution but the same:  `t= "There are 5 people in the class and their heights are 3,what about this!!,9,6,7,4"` will return 3

Comment: Astute observation! If you want to solve this problem, you need to replace regex with the following: `[\d,]+[,\d]+[^a-z]`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. `\d` is a digit (a character in the range 0-9), and `+` means 1 or more times

```
import re 

test_string = "There are 2 apples for 4 persons 4 helasdf 4 23 "


print("The original string : " + test_string) 

temp = re.findall(r'\d+', test_string) 
res = list(map(int, temp)) 


print("The numbers list is : " + str(res))
```

Comment: This fails OPs given test case.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that with the OP's string, let me try something.

Answer (score 0):

To extract a sequence of numbers in any string:

```py
    import re

    # some random text just for testing
    string = "azrazer 5,6,4 qsfdqdf 5,,1,2,!,88,9,44,aa,2"
    # retrieve all sequence of number separated by ','
    r = r'(?:\d+,)+\d+'
    # retrieve all sequence of number separated by ',' except the last one
    r2 = r'((?:\d+,)+)(?:\d+)'
    # best answers for question so far
    r3 = r'[\d,]+[,\d]+[^a-z]'
    r4 = r'[\d,]+[,\d]'

    print('findall r1: ', re.findall(r, string))
    print('findall r2:', re.findall(r3, string))
    print('findall r3:', re.findall(r4, string))
    print('-----------------------------------------')
    print('findall r2:', re.findall(r2, string))
```

Out put:

```
findall r1:  ['5,6,4', '1,2', '88,9,44']  ---> correct
findall r3: ['5,6,4 ', '5,,1,2,!', ',88,9,44,']  --> wrong
findall r4: ['5,6,4', '5,,1,2,', ',88,9,44,', ',2'] --> wrong
-----------------------------------------
findall r2: ['5,6,', '1,', '88,9,']  --> correct exclude the last element
```